# CSS Issue on iPad/iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, ios, css, ipad

I have extensive experience in CSS and I cannot figure out what's going on with this one site I'm working on:

http://lockwoodstorage.com/

Everything looks fine on all browsers but on iPhone and iPad, the content backgrounds cut off on the left side. I've tried media queries and I've tried to locate in the browsers what container could be causing this but I can't seem to figure it out.

I know this is a pretty basic question (and I always use Stack Overflow as last resort) but perhaps there is an issue here that I'm not versed in (and that could help in the forum in the future; I will update the question if it is something more complex). Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

### EDIT

FYI, I'm not trying to make this site responsive. I'm just trying to make it display correctly on iPhone and iPad. I've also been seeing an issue where the load time is SUPER slow on iOS for some reason.

When putting this site together, I used the Twenty Twelve theme and just customized it to my liking. It wasn't a responsive theme, just a basic one.

I've put a bounty out for this. Have at it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you please show a picture of your problem, and another picture of what is the intended solution. I, and maybe others, don't have an iPhone or iPad to test with.

Comment: Update: I see that #page has a max-height of 485px, which causes the blue background to become smaller on mobile, exposing the striped background behind it. Is this what you mean? If so, change max-height: 485px to min-height: 485px, or possibly less because it looks like the picture you have in there isn't 485px in height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your header  you are using CSS float:left property which is causing this problem.Just remove this CSS property and your problem will be solved.

And then if you want to float your elements to the left in header you can do it by targeting each individual element. for Example

```
#logo, #nav
{
 float:left;
}
```

Also @`<div id=page>` change max-height to min-height and you all set to go. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `min-height:485px` at the place of `max-height:485px`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to make a website responsive you should build it mobile first. That way you can style each element with regards to the device to it gets displayed correctly, adding break points along the way for bigger devices.

At the moment it looks like you have built the site for desktop and then added a few media queries to reposition elements to try and make them fit. This will create more work for you and will definitely be frustrating.

If you want the site looking good on all devices I would recommend starting with mobile and restyling it, then work your way up to tablet and then desktop.

Comment: I've based this on a WordPress template. I didn't add the queries in, I just used existing ones. The site is not to be responsive, I just need it to display correctly on mobile and it's not. Do you see that issue on your end?

Comment: In that case I think you can just remove the media queries and the viewpoint in the head of the document. Then the desktop version should display on the mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Mx I'll also agree with David. you should develop it mobile first because the way you are trying to customize it for mobile will take a lot of time and effort if you have issues in many places.

if you have issues in few places you can do it by putting media queries, Percentages for widths and heights instead of fix values. similarly you can use em instead of pixels where ever required.

However, as I mentioned earlier this will take more time to customize. So, i'll suggest to use Zurb Foundation or Twitter Bootstrap.